# Get REST Call is not returning the string I put in url

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc, api, rest, get

I have very simple code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace Calculator.Controllers
{
    public class CalcController : ApiController
    {

        public string Get(string type)
        {

            return type;
        }

    }
}
```

And this is what it returns when I type in http://www.example.com/api/calc/test

```
<string xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" i:nil="true"/>
```

When I use http://www.example.com/api/calc/?type=test it returns this:

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">test</string>
```

How to I make it so I can just do the top one instead of the bottom one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a route in `Global.asax.cs` above the default one.

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "route1",
    routeTemplate: "api/calc/{type}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Calc" }
);
```

Comment: Two thing I don't have a default one and after adding this here: `public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.MapHttpRoute(name: "route1",routeTemplate: "api/Calc/{type}", defaults: new { controller = "Calc" }
);
        }`

Comment: No it is not working it still returns this: `<string xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" i:nil="true"/>`

Comment: One other interesting thing that is happening is it is giving me : `redundant argument name specification`